# Symmetric difference - equality proofs.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic, proof-writing

I have a couple of statements to prove (self-learning, not homework). I'm not able to proceed with any of them (I've tried starting from RHS, LHS, etc.). I suppose I'm missing something. I would like to receive some tips or a solution for one of them and I will try to solve the rest.

The symmetric difference is defined as follows: $A \triangle B = (A \setminus B) \cup (B \setminus A)$.

$(A \cup B) \triangle C = (A \triangle C) \triangle (B \setminus A)$.

$(A \cap B) \triangle C = (A \triangle C) \triangle (A \setminus B)$.

$(A \setminus B) \triangle C = (A \triangle C) \triangle (A \cap B)$.

Comment: Please ask one question at a time.

Comment: One way to get a better understanding of what's going on would be to draw some Venn diagrams.  This would be especially straightforward for the three identities you wanted to show, since each of them involves only three sets: $A$, $B$, and $C$.

Comment: You could also verify the three identities using truth tables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

E.g. the first one; try to show two inclusions.

Suppose $x \in (A\cup B)\Delta C$. Then there are two cases:

1. $x \in A \cup B$ and $x \notin C$. Then subcase a: $x \in A$ and then $x \in A \Delta C$ (as $x \in A \setminus C$) while $x \notin B\setminus A$ (as $x \in A$), and so $x \in (A \Delta C)\Delta (B \setminus A)$. Or subcase b: $x \in B$ while $x \notin A$ and then $x \in B \setminus A$ and $x \notin A \Delta C$ (as $x \notin C$ and $x \notin A$). Again $x \in (A \Delta C)\Delta (B \setminus A)$.
2. $x \in C$ or $x \notin A \cup B$. This is easier, as then $x \in C$, $x \notin A$ and $x \notin B$ so $x \in A \Delta C$ (from $C \setminus A$) and $x \notin B \setminus A$ (from $x \notin B$) and again $x \in (A \Delta C)\Delta (B \setminus A)$.

So the left to right inclusion has been shown now.

The right to left inclusion has similar cases.

Try it, and then the rest. Verify the claims first by drawing a Venn diagram for three sets in general position.

Answer (score 1):

A nice method is using characteristic (indicator) functions. Let $U$ be some universal set. For a subset $A\subseteq U$, let function $\chi_A\colon U\to \mathbb R$ be defined as $$\chi_A(x) = \begin{cases} 1, & x\in A,\\ 0, & x\not\in A. \end{cases} $$

Notice that $A = B$ if and only if $\chi_A = \chi_B$.

You can prove the following rules easily from the definition of characteristic functions:

\begin{align}
\chi_U &= 1,\\
\chi_{A^c} &= 1- \chi_A,\\
\chi_{A\cap B} &= \chi_A\chi_B,
\end{align}
and then using that it also follows:
\begin{align}
\chi_\emptyset &= \chi_{U^c} = 1-\chi_U = 0,\\
\chi_{A\cup B} &= 1 - \chi_{(A\cup B)^c} = 1-\chi_{A^c\cap B^c}\\ &= 1 - (1-\chi_A)(1-\chi_B)\\ &= \chi_A + \chi_B - \chi_A\chi_B = \chi_A + \chi_B - \chi_{A\cap B},\\
\chi_{A\setminus B} &= \chi_{A\cap B^c} = \chi_A (1-\chi_B),\\
\chi_{A\triangle B} &= \chi_{A\setminus B}+\chi_{B\setminus A}-\chi_{(A\setminus B)\cap(B\setminus A)}\\ &= \chi_A(1-\chi_B) + \chi_B(1-\chi_A) - \chi_\emptyset\\ &= \chi_A+\chi_B - 2\chi_A\chi_B.
\end{align}

Thus:

\begin{align}
\chi_{(A\cup B)\triangle C} &= \chi_{A\cup B}+\chi_C - 2\chi_{A\cup B}\chi_C \\
&= (\chi_A + \chi_B -\chi_A \chi_B) + \chi_C - 2(\chi_A + \chi_B -\chi_A \chi_B)\chi_C\\
&= \chi_A+\chi_B+\chi_C - \chi_A\chi_B - 2\chi_A\chi_C - 2\chi_B\chi_C + 2\chi_A\chi_B\chi_C,\\ \\
\chi_{(A\triangle C)\triangle(B\setminus A)} &= \chi_{A\triangle C}+ \chi_{B\setminus A} - 2 \chi_{A\triangle C}\chi_{B\setminus A}\\
&= \chi_{A\triangle C}+\chi_B(1-\chi_A)-2(\chi_A+\chi_C-2\chi_A\chi_C)\chi_B\chi_{A^c}\\
&= \chi_{A\triangle C}+\chi_B(1-\chi_A)-2(\chi_{A\cap A^c}\chi_B+\chi_{A^c}\chi_B\chi_C-2\chi_{A\cap A^c}\chi_B\chi_C)\\
&= (\chi_A+\chi_C-2\chi_A\chi_C)+(\chi_B-\chi_A\chi_B)-2(1-\chi_{A})\chi_B\chi_C\\
&= \chi_A+\chi_B+\chi_C - \chi_A\chi_B - 2\chi_A\chi_C - 2\chi_B\chi_C + 2\chi_A\chi_B\chi_C,
\end{align}

and so the two sets are equal.

Sidenote, it's also true that $A\subseteq B$ iff $\chi_A\leq \chi_B$.